# Enable/Disable firebase push notifications in react native app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I have a react app with settings screens which allows to disable all types of notifications. How to achieve this wasn't exactly clear in [react native documentation](https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/). I can ask for user permission when he signup but how do I disable this permission from settings screen so he will not receive any notifications but user can enable them again in future.

I can do this using topics but that's pretty limited. I want to target using audience from firebase console. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Save this as a flag in user's profile and if the user has turned it OFF just don't send a push

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this. you need to check platform and do the configuration respectively.

For Android to check notification status you need `react-native-permissions` [library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions).

`import {checkNotifications} from 'react-native-permissions';`

Depending on the `notification` you can enable and disable the button.

```
async checkNotificationStatus(){
    if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
        const authStatus = await messaging().hasPermission();
        if(authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED) {
            this.setState({
                notification: true
            })
        }else{
            this.setState({
                notification: false
            })
        }
    }else{
        checkNotifications().then(({status}) => {
            if(status === 'granted'){
                this.setState({
                    notification: true
                })
            }else{
                this.setState({
                    notification: false
                })
            }
        });
    }
}
```

to Enable and Disable when button click. you can simply navigate the user to System settings

```
   async toggleNotification(){
        if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
            const authStatus = await messaging().hasPermission();
            if (authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.NOT_DETERMINED) {
                const authorizationStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
                if (authorizationStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED) {
                    this.setState({
                        notification: true
                    })
                }
            } else{
                Linking.openURL('app-settings://')
            }
        }else{
            Linking.openSettings();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So there is no way to turn off notifications automatically for android?